# how to refresh invisible area item of Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I try to refresh a Visible item with updateView()

```
public synchronized void updateView(int position, ChatItem item){
    int firstItemIndex = chatListView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
    int lastItemIndex = chatListView.getLastVisiblePosition();
    if (position >= firstItemIndex && position <= lastItemIndex) {
        View view = chatListView.getChildAt(position - firstItemIndex);
        updateOneData(position, item);
        bindView(position, view, chatListView);
    } else {

    }
}
```

but,how to refresh invisible area item of Android ListView ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to handle *Visible* and *Invisible* items, just update your `adapter` data and call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged()) to refresh the views.

Comment: yes, that is a right method.but why i need to handle Visible and Invisible, that is sometime i want to refresh only one item not all.

Comment: Its required to use this method for one or many items update(s). But if you want to use your updateView() method, you don't need o handle invisible items... just update the data in your adapter and when the list reach the invisible updated item, it will get the new data. In other words, you don' need to update an invisible View.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
listView.invalidateViews();
```